# which is one is faster Hbase or Hypertable?

Tags: c++, nosql

I had a requirement to store millions of records in which all are unique with multiple columns.
for example

```
eventcode description count
526       blocked     100
5230       xxx         20
....
```

and I want the following requirements while fetching sorting on count column, filtering on columns.

So I thought of using Hbase but I googled up and known that hypertable is faster.

So I am bit confused to know it.
please help me regarding this.

Note: I want to use C++ for transactions (reading, writing).

Comment: What are you confused about. If you read from a reliable source that Hypertable is faster, then it must be faster...

Comment: Here is a discussion of this issue between HBase people and the maintainer of Hypertable, Doug Judd: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Addendum-to-Hypertable-vs-HBase-Performance-Test-w-mslab-enabled-td3740880.html

Answer (score 2):

BIG disclaimer: i work for hypertable.

We have created a benchmark a while ago which you can read here: http://hypertable.com//why_hypertable/hypertable_vs_hbase_2/
Conclusion: Hypertable is faster, usually twice as fast.

Performance actually was the reason why hypertable was founded. Back then some guys were sitting together and discussing an open source implementation of Google's bigtable architecture. They did not agree on the programming language (java vs. c++ - the disagreement was about performance). As a result, one group founded hypertable (a C++ implementation) and the other group started working on hbase (in java).

If you do not trust benchmarks then you will have to run your own; both systems are open source and free to use. If you have questions about hypertable or run into problems while evaluating it then feel free to drop me a mail (or use the mailing list - all questions are getting answered.)

Btw - hypertable does not (yet) support sorting. You will have to implement this in your client application.

Comment: And how do you compare Hypertable's speed to Aerospike or Hyperdex?